# python: how to call a function with a flexible parameter order?

Tags: python

Let us take an example. In certain libraries like "scipy.integrate" calling a function like "odeint" (integrating functions) has to be expressed as "odeint(func, y0, T, ...)" where "func" is a name of a function that has to be predefined with two parameters (y,t0), y vector and t0 a scalar.

The question is how to use "odeint" if the already defined function "func" is specified with two parameters but in the inverse order "(t0, y)".

Best regards.

Comment: Not too familiar with Python, but can't you just make a wrapper for `func()`, that takes parameters as `(y, t0)`, then switches them around and calls `func()`?

Comment: Thank u for you feed-back, could you give me more informations?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python's syntax, but what I was thinking was that if `odeint()` calls `func()` as `func(y, t0)`, but `func()` expects to be called as `func(t0, y)`, it should be possible to make a `funcwrapper()` that takes `(y, t0)`, then switches their order and calls `func(t0, y)`.  Something like Moses Koledoye's lambda suggestion, basically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lambda function to reorder the arguments like so:

```
odeint(lambda p, q: func(q, p), y0, T, ...)
```

Alternatively, you can supposedly swap the orders in the main call if all `odeint` does is call `func` on the arguments and does interact directly with the arguments:

```
odeint(func, T, y0, ...)
```

Comment: It is better to use abstract parameter names like `a` and `b` in a lambda to avoid confusion.

Comment: It's OK, it functions. Can we built and call an explicit function instead of a lambda function, how ?

Comment: @AriouatHanane `def f(p, q): return func(q, p)`

Comment: Yes but what is the value of func, couldn't it be a parameter of f to be reused ?

Comment: @AriouatHanane I don't understand what exactly you need. The answer here covers what you originally described as the problem.

Comment: Your responses are very good, but if we have to call several times odeint with different functions (func) we have to write several functions "f": is there a possibility to have a generic expression of function f.

Comment: If you didn't need `f`, would have it have been possible to call `odeint` without changing to the required function? No. That's why I suggested you use a lambda in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly call parameters in arbitrary sequence:

```
def func(a, b, c):
    print('a = {}'.format(a))
    print('b = {}'.format(b))
    print('c = {}'.format(c))

x = 1
y = 2
z = 3

func(a = x, b = y, c = z)
func(c = z, b = y, a = x)
func(b = y, c = z, a = x)
```

P.S. I'm not on 100% sure, but try `odeint(func, y0 = y0, T = T, ...)`

or `odeint(func, T = T, y0 = y0, ...)`.